# How to correct the deviation of reprojected MODIS L1B by using the gdalwarp?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, modis

I am working on reprojecting the MODIS L1B data which downloaded from [the NASA EOSDIS Reverb website](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search). The data is MOD021KM. I applied the gdalwarp command to convert the projection of the image to the WGS84.

```
gdalwarp -of GTIFF -r near -t_srs EPSG:4326 -overwrite -tr 0.018728541 -0.0089737573 HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD021KM.A2013145.1950.006.2014225011320.hdf":MODIS_SWATH_Type_L1B:EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB MOD021KM2013145_2.tif
```

However, the reporjected image by gdalwarp cannot be matched to the Lake mask in figure 1. In figure 2, the image which was projected by ENVI conversion toolkit is identical to the lake mask.

The right-bottom of the two figures shows the image extent via the coordinates of the four corners. It indicates the longitude is error in the figure 1. How do I correct the deviation of the image using gdalwarp.

[image]